# Javascript DIV Movement on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

NIm creating an animation that moves a div incrementally on scroll. I'm close but I don't think my code is the most efficient and I don't know how to adapt it to add more arguments. So for instance, hitting a certain height on the page will then move the object right and stop moving it down. Below is my JS and the codepen can be found at;

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KxHwu - Original

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DLxqg - Messing about with moving right

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var boxPosition = $('#box').position();
var row2Position = $('#row2').position();

var distance = $('#row2').offset().top,
    $window = $(window);

console.log(distance);

$window.scroll(function() {
    if ( $window.scrollTop() >= distance - 400 ) {
      var st = $(window).scrollTop();
      console.log(st);

      $('#box').css({top: 0 + st});

      //CODE NOT WORKING

      if(st >= 270) {
        var boxPos = $('#box').position();
        console.log(boxPos.left);
        $('#box').css({left: boxPos.left + st});
      }

      //
    lastScrollTop = st;

    }
});
```

I'm looking for the box to start scrolling like it does, then when it hits half of row 2 scroll right.

I hope I have explained this in an easy way!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tHwlq

Here is an example of how to do it; you'll need to tweak the numbers to make it work as you plan.

```
var $window = $(window);
var $box = $("#box");

$window.scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();

    if (scrollTop >= 250 && scrollTop < 400) {
      $box.css({top: -250 + scrollTop});      
    } else if(scrollTop >= 400 && scrollTop < 600) {
      $box.css({left: (50+(scrollTop-400)/2)+"%"})
    }
});
```

If your project has numerous elements like this, I'd recommend the ScrollMagic (http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/) library.

As far as efficiency is concerned I'd recommend the following:

1) Cache the jQuery selectors (note $box variable). Otherwise, jQuery will have to query the DOM on every scroll event.

2) Cache scrollTop rather then querying it multiple times within the event callback.

3) Although `left` and `top` work, using the `transform: translate()` property is more efficient, especially on mobile devices. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform). However, on most mobile devices, scroll events only fire at the completion of a scroll, not while a page is scrolling.

Comment: Thanks for your response Jason, this is perfect. How would I go about adding another argument to say when its scrolled so far left then start scrolling down? Add an extra else if? I'm assuming I would need to reset scrolltop again as well as detecting how far right the box has went?

Comment: Yup, add another `else if`.

Comment: If performance is actually an issue, **PURE** Javascript is the way to go. Using jQuery only to place the event handler and the processing completely done using pure old fashioned Javascript.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel is correct, pure javascript is faster and less download. And loading jQuery for just a few simple tasks is superfluous. However, in this implementation, it may download faster, but I'd doubt you'd see any noticeable performance increase due to the simplicity of the task.

Comment: @Jason Actually, you will. Everytime you scroll, the event is fired. The goal here is to do the job as quickly as possible. Nobody wants to scroll a page and wait 1-2s for it to process all the event handlers. I would say that a code that handles with scroll or resize or other UI events shouldn't take more than 20ms. But your answer works and it's a really good answer. I disagree with your usage of the `window` object, when you already have the information you need without jQuery. Other than that, it's a great answer.

Comment: 1-2s to process an event handler? That is a heck of an event handler. So, I built a little test on jsperf.com (http://jsperf.com/jquery-scroll-event). Please let me know if the code I used to test here is flawed. Oddly enough, jQuery came out ahead...which doesn't make sense to me. I expected it to Javascript in the lead by a small margin. Your thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Now upto this stage - thanks for your help, but I'm looking to then transform this box to a smaller size. Should I post a separate question for this or is it just a case of using that transform

Comment: Transform should work. Just remember to include the necessary browser prefixes and note that slightly different syntax. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform

Comment: How would the syntax look for the .css? so when scrolling the scale is linked to the scroll? I've updated the pen at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uFykD but that syntax isn't correct :(